# Ants and goo in Euclid?

Tags: plot-explanation, pi

There are scenes shown in the movie `Pi` which have ants and goo in the protagonist's apartment which also houses his computer `Euclid`. Is there any significance of these ants/goo?

Really lame pun makes me think it could denote *bugs* in a computer program but from what I hear about New York City's cleanliness, it could denote the commonly found dirt.

Does anyone know what the real significance of these is?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the ideas you cite, there's also the notion of going "buggy" — that is, mad — as the messiness of organic life interferes with the functioning of computers and pure math.

Comment: Yes, that maybe correct as well, so what **is** the real reason?

Answer (score 0):

It is more to suggest the intelligence that might be being developed in the computer, an awareness.

Really once Euclid found the answer, as is said many times in the movie, everything is infused with the spiral. The spiral is the answer to the universe

Comment: But does intelligence have to do with bugs and goo?